# YII2 json_encode returns empty

Tags: json, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Why does this returns empty 
`{}`?

```
$model=  \common\models\rps\RpsChecklist::findOne($id);
return json_encode($model);
```

I tried `return json_encode($model->id);` it returns just the exact ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`findOne()` will return an active record object. In your case is `RpsChecklist` model.

If you want to use `json_encode()` function, object must be array.
So my solution is:

```
$model=  \common\models\rps\RpsChecklist::find()->where(['id' => $id])->asArray()->one();
return json_encode($model);
```

Goodluck and have fun.

Comment: It gives this response `"[{\"imsi\":\"899204031015\"},{\"imsi\":\"8992040310\"},{\"imsi\":\"89920403101519\"}]"` and I want to remove `\` from it